# Set new onChange function to go to based on the page it called from

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a controller that exist in multiply pages, What I need is `onChange` function of `asp:FileUpload` control  will be different from page to page (unique to each page):

**Call to controller**

```
<PLWeb:_AdminProductFileUpload runat="server" ID="fuThumb"/>
```

**The controller "_AdminProductFileUpload.ascx"**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FU_hdn" runat="server" onchange="updateFileLbl(this)"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFU" OnClientClick="fuClick(this); return false;" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFU" />
```

The function `updateFileLbl` exist in a js file that gets loaded when the controller get loaded

**What i am trying to achieve:**

If the controller is on page **A**:

The `onChange` function on `asp:FileUpload` element will be changed to `updateFileLbl_FromPageA(this)`

If the controller is on page **B**:

The `onChange` function on `asp:FileUpload` element will be changed to `updateFileLbl_FromPageB(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used that solution:

Add class (hdn-FU) to the `fileupload`

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FU_hdn" cssClass="hdn-FU" runat="server" onchange="updateFileLbl(this)"/>
```

and then "catch" the `onchange` event:

```
$(".hdn-FU").change(function(el){... what ever i want to do onchange event ...}
```

- This way the original `updateFileLbl` will get called and the change event will be called after.